# Filtrar tabela antes de aplicar um LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-select, join

Eu tenho duas tabelas e quero todos os elementos da primeira - independentemente da condição do JOIN (o que caracteriza um LEFT JOIN) - mas antes disso quero filtrar a segunda tabela. Por exemplo:

Tabela Cliente:

```
    ╔══════════╦═══════╗
    ║ Cliente  ║ Flag  ║
    ╠══════════╬═══════╣
    ║ A        ║ S     ║
    ║ B        ║ V     ║
    ║ C        ║ L     ║
    ╚══════════╩═══════╝
```

Tabela Entrada:

```
   ╔══════════╦═════════╦═══════════╗
   ║ Cliente  ║ Entrada ║ Categoria ║
   ╠══════════╬═════════╬═══════════╣
   ║ A        ║    5575 ║ D         ║
   ║ A        ║    6532 ║ C         ║
   ║ A        ║    3215 ║ D         ║
   ║ A        ║    5645 ║ M         ║
   ║ B        ║    3331 ║ A         ║
   ║ B        ║    4445 ║ D         ║
   ╚══════════╩═════════╩═══════════╝
```

OK. Executando um LEFT JOIN  Eu terei todos os Cliente independentemente de haverem itens relacionados na tabela Entrada, mas antes disso eu quero filtrar esta última pela Categoria = D - antes do JOIN.

Resultado desejado:

```
   ╔══════════╦═══════╦═════════╗
   ║ Cliente  ║ Flag  ║ Entrada ║
   ╠══════════╬═══════╬═════════╣
   ║ A        ║ S     ║  5575   ║
   ║ A        ║ S     ║  3215   ║
   ║ B        ║ A     ║  4445   ║
   ║ C        ║ L     ║  NULL   ║
   ╚══════════╩═══════╩═════════╝
```

Se eu utilizar a pesquisa abaixo eu perderei o último item do resultado desejado:

```sql
   SELECT c.Cliente, c.Flag, e.Entrada
   FROM Cliente AS c
   LEFT JOIN Entrada AS e
   ON c.Cliente = e.Cliente
   WHERE e.Categoria='D'
```

Como fazer para obter o resultado desejado inicialmente?

Answer (score 2):

Não seu se seria mais performático mas se fosse executado o `left join` na tabela já filtrada como uma `subquery`. Sei que `subqueries` não são muito performáticas mas como está indexado pode ser mais rápido.

```
SELECT 
    c.Cliente, c.Flag, e.Entrada
FROM 
    Cliente AS c
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT ent.Entrada FROM Entrada as ent WHERE ent.Categoria = 'D') AS e
        ON (c.Cliente = e.Cliente)
```

Comment: Agradeço a resposta @felipe-caputo. Eu tinha feito o teste com esta sintaxe e o problema do tempo também acontece. No post original ela também foi sugerida e o autor concordou que retornam o mesmo resultado (mas a minha resposta abaixo seria mais eficiente). Se achou a pergunta boa agradeço um UP-VOTE ;)

Answer (score 0):

Estudando via o [post original](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15077053/filter-table-before-applying-left-join) onde encontrei minha dúvida respondida, e [um outro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12400567/difference-between-on-and-and-on-where-in-sql-left-join) que discute a diferença entre ON e WHERE no LEFT JOIN cheguei a conclusão de que a resposta mais adequada é a seguinte:

```sql
   SELECT c.Cliente, c.Flag, e.Entrada
   FROM Cliente AS c
   LEFT JOIN Entrada AS e
   ON c.Cliente = e.Cliente
   AND e.Categoria='D'
```

Porém, para uma situação com uma tabela Cliente com 150K entradas e uma tabela Entrada com 450K entradas, minha pesquisa não termina nem depois de 30 minutos. Pra ter um ponto de comparação quando troco o último AND por WHERE o retorno é instantâneo. Eu deveria esperar esta perda de performance (detalhe, todos os campos envolvidos são indexados)? Alguma outra sugestão de pesquisa que seja em teoria mais rápida?

Answer (score 0):

Como regra genérica você deixa no join apenas o necessário para as tabelas serem comparadas entre si, no seu caso apenas o c.Cliente = e.Cliente.

E você deixa no where aquilo apenas que for o filtro, no caso o WHERE e.Categoria='D'.

engines de sistemas modernos vão saber se auto otimizar independente da situação. Infelizmente não conheço a engine do MySql para saber se ela é esperta o bastante para se auto ajustar.

Como, em geral, o WHERE é realizado apenas após o JOIN essa perda de performance é esperada.
Vejamos colocando a condição de filtro junto com o join para TODO registro da tabela entrada você vai verificar se a categoria = D E se tem um correspondente em cliente

No segundo caso ele já diminuiu muito a busca, pois só vai verificar a categoria para entradas que tem cliente e possivelmente não há index cobrindo a categoria (e geralmente nem vale a pena criar indíces para flags)